# how to remove first N or last N lines from csv

Tags: python, csv

I used to get a csv from external system with data seperated with semicolon but now it also contains some metadata in first 10 lines/rows and last last 2 lines/rows.

Could please someone help me to understand how to remove them using python/pyspark?

for ex:csv structure

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNEak.png)

Please provide some suggestions.
Thanks!

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Just copy-paste the text into your question (and format as a code block).

Comment: Read the file with the CSV module into a list. Then slice the list to remove the first and last N lines.

Comment: How large are the files? What code do you use to read them currently?

Comment: Please provide the CSV data here as text along with your desired output.

Comment: Easiest is to use `pd.readcsv()` [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) with `skiprows` and `skipfooter` arguments (if the number of rows at start and bottom to skip are known). assuming you can use Pandas

Comment: You don't even need to use the CSV module for this (let alone pandas). You're just handling line-oriented data

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Everyone, thank you for the suggestions.
just to clear - i used to recieve a multiple csv's with with medium to large amount of columnar data.
nut now i also recieved additional metadata inofrmation in first 10 lines of csv like author, account,description information etc..
also , i am recieving 2 extra cloumns in the end as additional metadata information.

This is breaking my data pipeline processing. my whole aim to keep the structure as before.
i am working on azure databricks and we recieved files in datalake via an external process.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file in 'r+' mode (because you're going to rewrite it). Read all lines into a list. Seek to BOF and call writelines() with a slice of your input list. Don't forget to call truncate()

```
FILENAME = 'foo.csv'

with open(FILENAME, 'r+') as data:
    lines = data.readlines()
    data.seek(0)
    data.writelines(lines[10:-2])
    data.truncate()
```

Comment: This will buffer all of the data into memory, though.

Comment: @AKX Did you see anything about memory constraints in the question? Maybe I missed it. Or perhaps you're just being your usual pedantic self

Comment: I think that this answer, and the OP, are making some bold assumptions that the data will **always** be after the first 10 lines and before the final 2. The data appears to be a report describing products and customers. If the data ever contained additional/fewer lines in the beginning or end, this would corrupt the data by completely replacing the original files. IMO that's a bit dangerous and if nothing else the OP should start by simply validating the data that they've parsed.

Comment: @h0r53 The question is very specific. Sure, there could be issues if there turns out to be more leading and/or trailing extraneous data but that's not what the question asks. Furthermore, the sample shown is a very small file and there's no suggestion (that I can see) in the question that the file might be very much bigger

Comment: I just wanted to note this will buffer the data to memory. That may or may not be an issue for OP. Given it _looks_ like the data they care about starts with a line starting with Products and ends when there are no more lines starting with a product ID, an iterator with state sounds like it'd fit their needs better.

Comment: Just pointing out that the OP may very well be modeling a solution incorrectly by making assumptions about the report layout. That and this solution will permanently erase the original data, so such an incorrect model could be devastating in some contexts. But the answer as provided will solve the problem as provided and misjudgment by the OP is certainly not your fault.